Weird random reset of variable in react and framer motion
I'm making a draggable wheel, in react with framer motion.
You can see the code here. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wheel-f4mpxn?file=%2Fsrc%2FWheelContener.tsx%3A36%2C3-52%2C4
but here is the important part :
export const WheelContener = () => {
  const constraintsRef = useRef(null);
  const [wheelRotation, setWheelRotation] = useState(50);
  let xOrigin = useRef(0);
  let yOrigin = useRef(0);
  let xPosition = useRef(0);
  let yPosition = useRef(0);
  function DragStart(event, info) {
    xOrigin.current = info.point.x;
    yOrigin.current = info.point.y;
    setIsDragging(true);
  }
   
  function whileDrag(event, info) {
    xPosition.current = info.point.x;
    yPosition.current = info.point.y;
    var sAngle = Math.atan2(
      yOrigin.current - window.innerHeight / 2,
      xOrigin.current - window.innerWidth / 2
    );
    var pAngle = Math.atan2(
      yPosition.current - window.innerHeight / 2,
      xPosition.current - window.innerWidth / 2
    );
    var inc = ((pAngle - sAngle) * 180) / Math.PI;        
    setWheelRotation(+inc);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div className="drag-area" ref={constraintsRef}>
        <motion.div
          className="wheel"
          style={{ rotate: wheelRotation }}
        >
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div
          className="knob"
          drag
          dragConstraints={constraintsRef}
          onDrag={whileDrag}
          onDragStart={DragStart}
          onDragEnd={DragEnd}
        />
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
};

It's working fine, most of the time, but some time the variable that set the wheel rotation is reset to 0.
This is weird, because I can't see any pattern making this resetting occur. It's very random.
How it works :
on drag start you store the origin point, and then on drag you calculate the angle from it, and increment the wheel rotation.
If any one has an idea, that would be great, I'm stuck on this for some time now, it's very frustrating that it's so random, I can't think of any way to debug it.
I'm thinking it's probably an issue with the way I used react, because I'm still not very familiar with how it works, I might have done a newbie error that is very obvious to a react expert.
Thanks,

Given how you're describing the problem. It sounds like the component itself might be unmounted and remounted by some process higher up which will cause the state to be reset to null.
It might be worth looking into that.

Yes I think you're write @Barry Michael Doyle, but if I console log the monting unmounting it happen all the time, and doesn't reset to null. what would you change to prevent the component from being unmonted or the reset to happen if it does ? is it because I use useState ? Should I use something else ?

Ok so I don't think the problem comme from the reseting of the wheelRotation, because instead of null, I changed it to 50, but when the bug append, it still reset to 0, not 50. This is what the console return when I ask it the wheelRotation and the increment value. when you drag : "set wheelRotation = 72+4.61580649532456"
"set wheelRotation = 4.61580649532456+4.61580649532456" It goes from 72 + 4, to 4. It's really strange.

Ok, So I found out I should use a functional setState instead of a regular one. But I don't know how to do it. Can someone help please ?

When I try setWheelRotation((w) => w + inc); it start an infinite loop that crash every thing
